# Suficient condition for an unital $C^*$-algebra homomorphism to be surjective on postive elements.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

I am trying to find sufficient conditions for an unital $C^*$-algebra homomorphism $\alpha:A \rightarrow B$ to be surjective on positive elements, that is, $\alpha(A_+)=\alpha(B_+)$. For example, if the range of $\alpha$ is a hereditary subalgebra of $B$, then one has that all elements $b \in B_+$ such that $b \leq 1$ are in $\alpha(A_+)$, however I don't know what to do with the rest of the elements.

For a particular case, let $\alpha: C(S^1) \rightarrow C(S^1)$ be the endomorphism $f(z) \mapsto f(z^2)$, I was trying to prove it is surjective on positive elements with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Concerning $C(S^1)$ or equivalently $C_{per}[0,2\pi],$ the range of the mapping $f(\theta)\mapsto f(2\theta)$ consists of continuous functions with period $\pi.$ Not every positive function with period $2\pi$ has period $\pi.$ For example $2+2\cos\theta$ or $2+z+z^{-1}$ in $C(S^1).$ Another explanation: $\int_{S^1}f(z^2)z\,dz =0.$ For $g(z)=2+z+z^{-1}$ we have $\int_{S^1}g(z)z\,dz=1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha(A_+)=B_+$, then the range of $\alpha$ is contained in the subspace spanned by $B_+$ since $\alpha$ is a linear map. As every element in a $C^\ast$-algebra is a linear combination of four positive elements, the range of $\alpha$ must be $B$.

Conversely, assume that $\alpha$ is surjective. Every positive element of $B$ is of the form $b^\ast b$ with $b\in B$. By surjectivity, there exists $a\in A$ such that $\alpha(a)=b$. Hence $\alpha(a^\ast a)=b^\ast b$. Therefore $\alpha(A_+)=B_+$.

Comment: Omg yes, I was missing the first implication. Thanks a lot!